# Exporting with ox-publish, can not assign variable to Keyword

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, org-mode

I have a working setup with ox-publish and now i am trying to organize it. My problem is that i cannot assign a variable to the keyword-symbols like in the snippet below.

```
(setq my-org-base-dir "~/documents/todo")
(setq my-org-exp-dir "~/documents/todo_html")
(require 'ox-publish)
(setq org-publish-project-alist
  '(
    ("org-notes"
     :base-directory my-org-base-dir
     :base-extension "org"
      ; ....
     )
    ("org-static"
     :base-directory my-org-base-dir
      ; ....
     )
    ("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))
    ))
```

Using `:base-directory "~/documents/todo"` works just fine but if i try to use the value from a variable (`:base-directory my-org-base-dir`) emacs gives me `Wrong type argument: stringp, org-base-dir` when i try to export.

How do i assign a value to a Keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist '( ... ))
```

you're setting the value of **org-publish-project-alist** to a literal list.  It's not that you can't "assign a value to a keyword [argument]", it's that quotation of a list prevents evaluation of variables within it.  E.g.,

```
(let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
  (setq foo '(a b c)))
;=> (a b c)               
; *not* (1 2 3)
```

To get the variables "interpolated" you either need to use **list** to construct the list, or use a backquote so that you can splice in the values.  E.g.,

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
  `(                                    ;; backquote (`), not quote (')
    ("org-notes"
     :base-directory ,my-org-base-dir   ;; comma (,) to splice value in
     :base-extension "org"
      ; ....
     )
    ("org-static"
     :base-directory ,my-org-base-dir   ;; comma (,)
      ; ....
     )
    ("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Edit: I think I may have misunderstood the question.  This answers the question in the title, but doesn't look like it's the issue that the OP is running into.*

You can't assign a value to a keyword.  From the Emacs Lisp manual (emphasis added):

> #### [11.2 Variables that Never Change](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Constant-Variables.html)
>
> In Emacs Lisp, certain symbols normally evaluate to themselves. These
>   include nil and t, **as well as any symbol whose name starts with ‘:’
>   (these are called keywords)**. **These symbols cannot be rebound, nor can
>   their values be changed.** Any attempt to set or bind nil or t signals a
>   setting-constant error. The same is true for a keyword (a symbol whose
>   name starts with ‘:’), if it is interned in the standard obarray,
>   except that setting such a symbol to itself is not an error.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i misunderstood the problem, that is why the tilte is missleading. Thx for the answer though.